# Which is the proper way to use State vs Props

Tags: react-native, apollo-client

Trying to figure out which is the way to handle data into react components.

Im actually trying these two ways:

A) The State Way

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
if (!nextProps.allPostsQuery.loading && !nextProps.allPostsQuery.error) {
  this.setState({
    postList: nextProps.allPostsQuery.allPosts,
  })
 }
}

render () {
    return (
        <FlatList data={this.state.postList}>
    )
}
```

B) The Prop Way

```
render () {
    return (
        <FlatList data={this.props.allPostQuery.data}>
    )
}
```

Any suggestions on which/why ?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that you have implement request from GraphQL because of the apollo-client tag. Hypothesize that if you do not implement Redux, so state way is to make sure the component be refresh because the render method will be triggered. If you already have Redux,  so props way is the best way because render method will be trigger when your data change in global state.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the props way directly. since you're using apollo-client, it is already saved in a redux store. so whenever there's an update in the data from any component, you'll also receive it in this component and thus automatically trigger a re-render.